# Normalizing data when retraining on the train and validation set

Tags: normalization, validation, train-test-split

It is often good practice to normalize training data for numerical stability and faster convergence. When using a train-validation-test split, it is recommended to calculate normalization parameters (mean, std) from only the train set to prevent data leakage.

However, it is also common practice to retrain the model on the train and validation sets combined after finding the best hyperparameters, to make use of the most data possible.

My question is when retraining the model on the train and validation sets, should normalization parameters be calculated based of the two sets combined, or still just the train set?

On one hand it seems the normalization should be done with respect to both since they are both used to train the model. However, the hyperparameters were selected with regards to data normalized only with respect to the train data, so including the validation set when finding normalization parameters may not produce optimal training data for the selected hyperparameters.